# How to draw multiple array entities on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to draw out all of the objects that I have in my `zombielist`. but I can't get it to work.

```js
var FatZombieWikki = new Image();
FatZombieWikki.src = "FatZombieWikki.png";

var Zombie = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.Draw = function(ctx) {
 ctx.drawImage(FatZombieWikki,200,ZombieY,50,50);
  }
  this.Update = function(){
 if(ZombieY < 900) {
   ZombieY += 0.5;
 } 
  }
}

var z = new Zombie(100, 200,);
var zombieList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  zombieList.push(new Zombie(40 * i, 100));
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `ctx.drawImage(FatZombieWikki,200,ZombieY,50,50);` works, you now have to call the `Draw()` method of all the zombies inside the array.

Comment: @Shilly do you mean inside the for loop or inside the zombielist array? + the ctx.drawImage(FatZombieWikki,200,ZombieY,50,50); works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call your draw function inside loop, after creating object.

***DEMO***

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
var FatZombieWikki = new Image();
FatZombieWikki.src = "//i.stack.imgur.com/ubK40.jpg";

FatZombieWikki.onload = function(){
  var zombieList = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    zombieList.push(new Zombie(40 * i, 30*i));
    zombieList[i].draw(ctx);
  }
}
var Zombie = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.drawImage(FatZombieWikki,this.x,this.y,50,50);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000
}
```

```html
<canvas id='c' width=500 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zombieList.forEach(zombie => zombie.Draw(ctx))
```

Comment: i get "ctx is not defined"

Comment: You said that `ctx.drawImage(FatZombieWikki,200,ZombieY,50,50); works`. You should use the same `ctx` here

Comment: Explain why or how this awnser would fix the problem instead of only a piece of code without any explaination.